# D3 Angular Tree

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a working D3 tree that I am trying to convert to Angular. It's a v3 tree.

The component code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
declare var d3: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree-view',
  template: '<div #chart id="chart"></div>',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.scss']
})
export class TreeViewComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createChart();
  }

  constructor(){

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.root.update = this.update;
    this.update(this.root);
  }

private treeData: any[] = [{...data here}],

tree: any;
i = 0;
duration = 750;
root:any = {};
svg:any = {};
diagonal: any;

@ViewChild('chart')
private chartContainer: ElementRef;


private createChart(): void {
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 1560 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 this.tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

  const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

 this.diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection((d) => { return [d.y, d.x]; });

 this.svg = d3.select(element).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

this.root = this.treeData[0];
this.root.x0 = height / 2;
this.root.y0 = 0;

this.hideChildren(this.root);

console.log(this.root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "1000px");
}

 private hideChildren(node) {
    if(node.children) {
        node._children = node.children;
        node.children = null;
        node._children.forEach((a) =>  { this.hideChildren});
    }
}

 private update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = this.tree.nodes(this.root).reverse(),
      links = this.tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach((d) => { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = this.svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, (d) => { return d.id || (d.id = ++this.i ); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", this.click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", (d) => { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", (d) => { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", (d) => { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text((d) => { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", (d) => { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = this.svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, (d) => { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", (d) => {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return this.diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr("d", this.diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr("d", (d) => {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return this.diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach((d) => {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  console.log('end creating chart');
}

// Toggle children on click.
click(d, item) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  this.update(d);
}


}
```

The script is compiled into the angular.json file using

`"scripts": ["src/scripts/d3.js"]`

However, when I expand a node I am getting an error of

> 5core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: this.update is not a function
>       at SVGGElement.push../src/app/tree-view/tree-view.component.ts.TreeViewComponent.click
>   (tree-view.component.ts:69898)
>       at SVGGElement.__onclick (d3.js:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
>       at SVGGElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)

Clearly this is as scoping issue - with`this`, but I don't know how to get around this. `this` refers to the node, not the class.

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers
KH

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using inline functions rather than members

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('on init');
        const createChart = () => {
            var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
                width = 1560 - margin.right - margin.left,
                height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            this.tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);

            const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

            this.diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection((d) => { return [d.y, d.x]; });

            this.svg = d3.select(element).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            this.root = this.treeData[0];
            this.root.x0 = height / 2;
            this.root.y0 = 0;

            hideChildren(this.root);

            d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "1000px");
        };


        const update = (source) => {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = this.tree.nodes(this.root).reverse(),
                links = this.tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach((d) => { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

            // Update the nodes…
            var node = this.svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, (d) => { return d.id || (d.id = ++this.i); });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
                .on("click", click);

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6)
                .style("fill", (d) => { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", (d) => { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", (d) => { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                .text((d) => { return d.name; })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(this.duration)
                .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", (d) => { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(this.duration)
                .attr("transform", (d) => { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                .remove();

            nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6);

            nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Update the links…
            var link = this.svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, (d) => { return d.target.id; });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", (d) => {
                    var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
                    return this.diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(this.duration)
                .attr("d", this.diagonal);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(this.duration)
                .attr("d", (d) => {
                    var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
                    return this.diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
                })
                .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach((d) => {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });

            console.log('end creating chart');
        };


        const hideChildren = (node) => {
            if (node.children) {
                node._children = node.children;
                node.children = null;
                node._children.forEach((a) => { hideChildren(a); });
            }
        };

        const click = (d) => {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }

            update(d);
        };

        createChart();
        this.root.update = update;
        update(this.root);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the example in Stackblitz. I am trying to implement a tree visualisation with D3 on Angular 9. I am getting confused as to how to implement the same.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvqfze , I created the Stackblitz example, but it's not working.